# Separating media from text with php

Tags: php, regex, text, element, media

I have a string that contains html composed on a text editor. Something like:

```
$string ='<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="alt text" width="1200" height="1650" class="full">
Lorem ipsum <a href="example.com">ergo</a> ipsum';
```

Other times like:

```
$string ='<iframe src="http://example.com/" width="1200" height="1650" class="full"></iframe>
<b>Lorem ipsum <a href="example.com">ergo</a> ipsum</b>'
```

Somehow I need to get media and text into separate 's but I'm not allowed to change the way content gets inputed on the string.

Ideally I would constrain all media to a separate field but I can't do that for multiple reasons.

I'm trying to work something out using regex but I can't get it to work.

The closest I got was by stripping tags but that does not get rid of the text:

```
echo '<div class="media">'.strip_tags($sting, '<img><iframe>').'</div><br>';
echo '<div class="text">'.strip_tags($string, '<p><a><b><stong>').'</div>';
```

Any insights? There might be a really clear solution out there..

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure if by media you meant the value of the src parameter or the tag type, but here's regex for either:

```
// result will be in $matches[1][0]
preg_match_all( '/src=\"(.*)\"/sU', $string, $matches ); 
preg_match_all( '/<(img|iframe)\s/sU', $string, $matches );
```